# mysql create stored procedure . what wrong with my code?

Tags: mysql

Error
SQL query: 
CREATE PROCEDURE GEN_MFREE( )  BEGIN ;
MySQL said: Documentation 
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2

what wrong with my code  ?
at below is my code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GEN_MFREE()
BEGIN
DECLARE CODE VARCHAR (10);
DECLARE BLOCK VARCHAR (10);
DECLARE UNIT VARCHAR (10);
DECLARE FLOOR VARCHAR (10);
DECLARE FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE LASTNAME VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE AMT DECIMAL(18,2) ;

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR SELECT 
                    B_resident.CODE,
                    B_resident.BLOCK,
                    B_resident.UNIT,
                    B_resident.FLOOR,
                    B_resident.FIRSTNAME,
                    B_resident.LASTNAME,
                    B_resident.TEL,
                    B_ResManFree.SIZE * B_ResManFree.FREE AS AMT,
                    '2016-01-01' AS MDATE
                FROM B_resident LEFT OUTER JOIN B_ResManFree ON 
                    B_resident.UNIT = B_ResManFree.UNIT AND 
                    B_resident.BLOCK = B_ResManFree.BLOCK 
                    WHERE B_resident.MAIN_CONT ='YES'
                    ORDER BY B_resident.BLOCK,B_resident.FLOOR,B_resident.UNIT

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  OPEN cursor_i;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor_i INTO CODE, BLOCK, UNIT, FLOOR, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AMT ;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO B_MfreeStatment(RES_CODE, 
                                RES_BLOCK,
                                RES_UNIT,
                                RES_FLOOR,
                                BAN_CODE,
                                RES_FIRSTNAME,
                                RES_LASTNAME,
                                AMT,MDATE) 
                            VALUES( CODE, BLOCK, UNIT, FLOOR,'001' FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AMT,'2016-01-01' );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor_i;
END;
;;
```

Comment: Questions like _"What is wrong with my code"_ are off-topics on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss to set the delimiter first:

```
Delimiter //

--> Your Code

--> End Code with // instead of ;;

Delimiter ;
```